# Как заставить Python увидеть libtorrent-rasterbar в mac os?

Tags: python-3.x

Пробую установить  libtorrent-rasterbar, но Python в упор не видит модуль. Система El Captaine.
Подскажите где искать?

```
andrew: ~ $ brew install python3
Warning: python3-3.6.0_1 already installed
andrew: ~ $ brew install libtorrent-rasterbar
Warning: libtorrent-rasterbar-1.1.1 already installed
andrew: ~ $ python
Python 3.6.0 (default, Mar  4 2017, 12:32:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libtorrent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libtorrent'
>>>
```

Comment: скорей всего, `libtorrent-rasterbar` установился для python2, а не для python3. Поэтому, запуская импорт в `python3`, не находится библиотека.

Comment: В python2 тоже самое

Comment: Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libtorrent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named libtorrent
>>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Команда `brew install libtorrent-rasterbar` не имеет прямого отношения к установке необходимых пакетов python, оно просто устанавливает системную библиотеку `libtorrent-rasterbar`. А вам нужен python-пакет. Соответственно:

- вам либо необходимо попросить менеджера пакетов `brew` установить также биндинги для python:

`brew install libtorrent-rasterbar --with-python`

- либо вам необходимо пользоваться инструментами для установки python-пакетов, - `pip`. В `python3` он должен быть умолчанию, попробуйте:

`pip install libtorrent-rasterbar`

, либо так:

`python -m pip install libtorrent-rasterbar`

Comment: Установил по новой brew install libtorrent-rasterbar --with-python.Теперь в консоли выдает          andrew: ~/torrents $ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 17 2016, 23:03:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libtorrent
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for boost::shared_ptr<libtorrent::alert> already registered; second conversion method ignored.

Comment: `RuntimeWarning` это предупреждение о свойствах установленной библиотеки. Во-первых, оно не является критической ошибкой и позволяет использовать `libtorrent-rasterbar`, а во-вторых, уже выходит за грани вашего вопроса. Для решения проблем с самой библиотекой задайте новый вопрос. Если мой ответ решил именно проблему установки библиотеки, и теперь python видит ее, то отметьте этот ответ правильным с помощью "галочки".

Comment: Спасибо большое !